# NodeJS, Log de conexões

Tags: node.js

Estou com um problema para cria uma base de LOG das conexões, consigo pegar praticamente todos os dados, porém o mais essencial que seria o corpo do Response, está retornando com `undefined`, alguém saberia como pegar esse valor

Segue código:

```js
const log = require('../utils/log');

function criaLog(req, res){
    let now = new Date;
    let dados = `Dados da requisicao:
    IP: ${req.ip},
    Headers: ${JSON.stringify(req.headers)},
    Rota: ${req.route.path},
    Metodo: ${req.route.stack[0].method},
    Data/Hora: ${now.getUTCDate()}/${(now.getMonth() + 1)}/${now.getFullYear()} ${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}
    Corpo: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)},
    Resultado Codigo: ${res.statusCode}, Mensagem: ${res.statusMessage},
    Corpo do Resultado: ${JSON.stringify(res.Body)}
    `;  
    log.escreveLog(dados);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Posso estar enganado mas, a syntax correta é com o body em minúsculo: `res.body`
- Verifique se você está enviando o body através do `res.send(req.body)` para acessar através do response

Answer (score 0):

Insira um evento de after no seu arquivo do servidor, dentro desse metodo passe os parametros desejados.

```
this.application.on('after', (req, res, next, err) => {

    let logger = {};
    let now = new Date();

    logger.ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

    logger.date = `[${req.date()}]`;

    logger.dataPesquisa = now.getUTCDate().toString() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1).toString() + '-' + now.getFullYear().toString();

    logger.method = req.method.toUpperCase();

    logger.url = req.url;

    logger.httpv = req.httpVersion;

    logger.status = res.statusCode;

    logger.body_Request = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    logger.body_Response = JSON.stringify(res._body);

    logger.headers = JSON.stringify(req.headers);
})
```